# Visual Studio Design View

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I used program C, and now im doing some web coding, is there a place I can switch the VS  toolbox layout from C++ to some kind of web design view? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Tools->Export and Import Settings, choose Reset all and you can change all settings to the predefined one for web development.

If you were using VS for some time I would suggest first exporting your actual settings, for a reference or if you will want to go back to them.